# Change an HTML input to textarea and copy over all the events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, textarea

I am trying to dynamically change a HTML input to a textarea field and convert it back to a text field. I can do that properly using the code given below but I am unable to copy over the events that happen on the text field. Is there a way I could copy over the events from the text field over to the textarea? If there is a better way to do this, kindly let me know.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WzE48/312/)

**HTML:**

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" name="fieldValue_0_3" onchange="alert('Hello WOrld');" value="this is a birthdate" tabindex="73">
<a href="#" id="change">Change</a>
<a href="#" id="changetext">Change To TextField</a>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Don't use inline javascript in your HTML and set event handler via javascript. Have an `input` and `textarea` in your HTML and hide one or the other when changing between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way

```
var textbox = $("#textbox"); $("#change").click(function () {
    $input = $("#textbox")
    $textarea = $("<textarea id='textarea'></textarea>").attr({
        id: $input.prop('id'),
        name: $input.prop('name'),
        value: $input.val(),
        onchange: $input.attr('onchange'),
        tabIndex: $input.prop('tabIndex')
    });
    $input.after($textarea).remove(); }); $("#changetext").click(function () {
    $textarea = $("#textbox")
    $input = $("<input></input>").attr({
        id: $textarea.prop('id'),
        name: $textarea.prop('name'),
        value: $textarea.val(),
        onchange: $textarea.attr('onchange'),
        tabIndex: $textarea.prop('tabIndex')
    });
    $textarea.after($input).remove(); });
```

**Fiddle:** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/WzE48/313/)

**Note:** Its always better to  take two different controls